# Improper convergent integral: differentiation of parameter

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm interested in the following integral:

$$I = -\int \limits_0^\infty \frac{\sin (\pi x)}{\log (x)} \mathrm{d}x$$

It can be shown by the courtesy of Dirichlet, that this integral converges; there are no singularities, the function $\sin \pi x/\log x$ is in fact continuous, so the only limit that might be the problem is $x \to \infty$, but, from the Dirichlet test, we know that $\sin \pi x$ has a bounded primitive function and $1/\log(x)$ is monotonically decreasing for $x > 1$.

The only thing that've come to my mind as to transform this is to exploit the following property:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a} x^a = x^a \log x$$

So I defined the following function:

$$G (a, b) \equiv - \int \limits_0^\infty e^{-b x} x^a \frac{\sin \pi x}{\log x}$$

And now we can see that

$$F (a, b) \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial a} G (a, b) \equiv - \int \limits_0^\infty e^{-b x} x^a \sin \pi x$$
which is computable and the result is:

$$F (a, b) = -\frac{\Gamma (1+a)}{\left( b^2 + \pi^2 \right)^{(1+a)/2}} \sin \left( (1+a) \arctan \frac{\pi}{b} \right)$$

Now I hope, that the following is true:

$$I = \lim_{b \to 0^+} G(0,b) = \lim_{b \to 0^+} \left[ \int \limits_C^0 F(a, b) \mathrm{d} a \right] = \int \limits_C^0 \lim_{b \to 0^+} F(a, b) \mathrm{d} a $$
$$\lim_{b \to 0^+} F(a, b) = - \frac{\Gamma (1+a)}{\pi^{1+a}} \cos \frac{\pi a}{2}$$

The final step is to find $C$ such that the calculation is easy. The actual value is $C = -1$, as this is Dirichlet integral, yielding $\pi/2$:

$$I = - \frac{\pi}{2} - \int \limits_{-1}^0 \frac{\Gamma (1+a)}{\pi^{1+a}} \cos \frac{\pi a}{2} \mathrm{d} a $$

The result is, however, wrong, because $I > 0$ and the right hand side is negative.

My goal is to express $I$ in terms of a simpler integral (not necessarily analytically) with a better asymptotic behaviour and/or over a finite interval.

**Is it possible to compute $I$ efficiently?**

Just a side note: it seems to me that it's impossible to practically compute $I$ by the definition, as the $\log(x)$ is increasing crazily slowly - that means the "$\infty$" would have to be very, very big to get a good approximation.

Comment: I believe you should have $$\int_C^0x^a\log(x)~\mathrm da=x^a$$which will require splitting over $|x|<1$ and $|x|>1$

Comment: You could always integrate by parts.

Comment: "by the courtesy of Dirichlet" That's a novel and very respectful way of paying gratitude to an old master. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the contour

[image]

contour integration gives
$$
\begin{align}
\overbrace{\color{#C00}{\text{PV}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{i\pi x}}{\log(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x}}^{\substack{\text{integral along the line}\\\text{minus an infinitesimal}\\\text{interval centered at $1$}}}+\overbrace{\vphantom{\int_0^\infty}\ \ \ \ \ \color{#00F}{\pi i}\ \ \ \ \ }^{\substack{\text{integral along}\\\text{an infinitesimal}\\\text{semicircular arc}\\\text{centered at $1$}}}
&=\overbrace{\color{#090}{\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-\pi x}}{\frac\pi2-i\log(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x}}^{\substack{\text{integral along the}\\\text{positive imaginary axis}}}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-\pi x}\left(\frac\pi2+i\log(x)\right)}{\frac{\pi^2}4+\log(x)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
since there are no singularities inside the contour and the integral along the black arc vanishes as the radius tends to $\infty$.

Taking the imaginary part of $(1)$, we get an integral that is far easier to evaluate numerically:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\log(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\pi+\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-\pi x}\log(x)}{\frac{\pi^2}4+\log(x)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\[6pt]
&\doteq-3.2191900386476588051\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Huh, that end result doesn't seem right at all. The integrand is overall monotonically decreasing, so it should be bounded between around $-3.1$ and $-3.3$.

Comment: I get the feeling the arc from $\infty$ to $i\infty$ plays a role, as we should have$$\int_{2n-1}^{2n+1}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\ln(x)}~\mathrm dx=\int_0^1\sin(\pi x)\left[\frac1{\ln(x+2n)}-\frac1{\ln(x+2n-1)}\right]~\mathrm dx<0\\\implies\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\ln(x)}~\mathrm dx<\int_0^3\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\ln(x)}~\mathrm dx<-2\ll-0.078$$

Comment: Ah, I think I see a problem. We have a simple pole at $x=1$.

Comment: There is no pole there since $\sin(\pi x)=0$ there.

Comment: But $e^{\pi i}\ne0$. Referring to your first line.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Thanks, that was the error.

Comment: :D Cool! And that verifies my result as well.

Comment: So this is a candidate (up to the final integral, which is a lot easier to compute) for the exact result? I have to think about that principal value and residue in 1. I'm kinda lost at the first =, where you rewrite it as some other integral. Are you using the residue theorem? Aren't we supposed to integrate over some closed curve, part of which is being pushed out to the infinity by some limiting process and some portion of the curve is the real line?

Comment: @user16320 It's a quarter circle contour, indented at 1. One line lies on the real line, and the other lies on the positive imaginary axis.

Comment: Ah, I see, but doesn't the residual theorem say, the result is $2 \pi i \sum_{res}$? So I kind of expect some sum of values out of that, not another integral...

Comment: Don't LISTEN TO ME! I'm stupid. That right-hand side integral is that imaginary axis...okay! You're greatest, I understand it now...I will check it and accept ^^

Comment: :P @user16320 Don't call yourself stupid over such mistakes. You can't view deleted comments, but I actually made similar mistakes when reading robjohn's answer, and likewise, robjohn had his fair share of mistakes here, so we're all in the same boat! xD

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the integrand is faily quadratic between integer values, hence

$$-I=\underbrace{\int_0^2\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\ln(x)}~\mathrm dx}_{\approx-3.64061894952}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\ln(x)}~\mathrm dx$$

$$\small\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\ln(x)}=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{t^2\ln^3(t)}\left[t^2\ln^2(t)+t(x-t)\ln(t)+\bigg[\ln(t)+2-\pi^2t^2\ln^2(t)\bigg]\frac{(x-t)^2}2\right]+\mathcal O((x-t)^3),\\t=n+0.5$$

This is a pretty close approximation and gives us the series

$$I\approx3.64061894952+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\underbrace{\frac{(-1)^n}{t^2\ln^3(t)}\left[\left(1-\frac{\pi^2}{24}\right)t^2\ln^2(t)+\frac{\ln(t)}{24}+\frac1{12}
\right]}_{a_n}$$

Which converges really slowly since $|a_n|\in\mathcal O(1/\ln(n))$, but by applying an Euler sum, convergence is rapidly sped up:

$$I\approx3.64061894952+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{2^{k+1}}\sum_{n=0}^k\binom kna_{n+2}$$

---

If one wishes to allow integrals into the sum,

$$I=3.64061894952-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{2^{k+1}}\sum_{n=0}^k\binom kn\int_{n+2}^{n+3}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\ln(x)}~\mathrm dx$$

Evaluating this up to $k=20$, I get

```
k    I_k
---- ------------
0    3.2884372794
1    3.2399068661
2    3.2264174379
3    3.2219217488
4    3.2202756011
5    3.2196366110
6    3.2193784711
7    3.2192711120
8    3.2192254632
9    3.2192057126
10   3.2191970462
11   3.2191931992
12   3.2191914749
13   3.2191906955
14   3.2191903408
15   3.2191901783
16   3.2191901035
17   3.2191900689
18   3.2191900528
19   3.2191900453
20   3.2191900418
```

By approximating further out, I get

\begin{align}I&\approx\int_0^{50}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\ln(x)}~{\rm d}x+\sum_{n=0}^{19}\frac1{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(-1)^k\int_0^1\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\ln(t+k+50)}~{\rm d}t\\&\approx\underline{-3.219190038646}743\end{align}

Comment: I got lost in the second row :/ How did you derive that complicated expression?  And yes, the sum in the third row coverges as slow as sum of alternating areas under the lobes of the original function, so very slow indeed. And finally, I don't get that covergence speed-up, instead of one sum you have to compute sum of the sum. The complexity computing N terms is ~N^2 (because of the inner sum). However, when I fed Mathematica with this, it seems that after a few terms (~10), the result of the sum stops at 0.403, so I ~ 4.044. When I tried I by definition, I couldn't get past 3.35.

Comment: In fact, when I increased the upper integration limit, result would decrease...

Comment: The second line follows by direct Taylor expansion if I didn't do it wrong... And yes, Euler summing increases complexity, but the rate of convergence is heavily sped up.

Comment: @user16320 By Euler summing the integral directly, I get $I\approx3.219$ using up to $x=13$.

Comment: And up to $x=23$, I got $I\approx3.2191900418$. Of course, there are likely some floating point errors, but this should be fairly close to the integral in question.

Comment: Note of course that there is a lot of error coming into my Taylor expansions, so while cheaper on the computer, they result is ultimately off quite a bit. :/